# What is the domain and range of the PMF of the Bernoulli distribution with p = 0.1?

Tags: probability, function

In probability theory and statistics, the [Bernoulli distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution)

> is the discrete probability distribution of a random variable which
>   takes the value 1 with probability p and the value 0 with probability
>   ${\displaystyle q=1-p}$.

The probability mass function f of this distribution, over possible outcomes k, is

> ${\displaystyle f(k;p)={\begin{cases}p&{\text{if }}k=1,\\q=1-p&{\text{if }}k=0.\end{cases}}}$

let p = 0.1, and then

$f(k;0.1)={\begin{cases}0.1&{\text{if }}k=1,\\0.9&{\text{if }}k=0.\end{cases}}$

So, the domain of this particular function f(k;0.1), its domain is the set {0,1} with 2 elements, and its range is the set {0.9,0.1} with 2 elements.

In this specific case, is my understanding right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Domain is the set of values that you can literally *evaluate* the function. Given the definition, you can't evaluate the function with $k$ outside the set $\{0,1\}$, which means it is indeed the domain of it. Note that wikipedia doesn't explicitly comment on the domain, but the support. However, if a discrete function is written in *piecewise* form like this and you don't see an *else* statement, it typically means you can't evaluate values other than listed in the definition.

Range is the set of values you can obtain when you *evaluate* the function within its domain. And, in this case, it is $\{p,1-p\}$ in general. For $p=0.5$, the range has only one element. Otherwise, it has two as you noted for $p=0.1$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What does "partial form" mean?

Comment: I've changed it as *piecewise*.

Comment: Does "... don't see an else statement" indicate that a PMF have to include the else part?

Comment: No, it doesn't have to include.

Comment: So, "can't evaluate values other than listed in the definition" only affects the generalization of this function, but the pmf $f(k;0.1)={\begin{cases}0.1&{\text{if }}k=1,\\0.9&{\text{if }}k=0.\end{cases}}$ here is legitimate, is it?

Comment: It is legitimate, you can evaluate $f$ for the values in the domain, i.e. $\{0,1\}$; but not for $k=2,3$ for example, since they're not in the domain as they're not included in the piecewise definition.

Comment: "k=2,3" is the concern about generalization, such that the Multinoulli distribution, is it?

Comment: Yes, it is a concern about its generalization, but what I'm really saying is this: you can't evaluate $k = 2,3$ or $-1$ for the Bernoulli distribution because it's not in the domain, and your understanding in the original question is right.

Comment: Thank you so much. What is the relationship between domain and support, in this particular case or any other simple example case?

Comment: I think it's better to contemplate on their definitions: domain is the values you can evaluate the function, support is the values the function is non-zero. So, the support is a subset of the domain, and sometimes they're equal. In this particular case, they're equal.

Comment: Would you please give an example that the support is not equal to domain?

Comment: The situation occurs more oftenly in continuous case: e.g. uniform distribution: https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Uniform_distribution_(continuous). By the way, in order to prevent this thread from elongating, it's better to frame your further questions as a separate one.

Comment: Normally, the domain of a pmf $p$ is taken to be $\mathbb R$ by defining $p(x)=0$ for all $x$ not in the support of the distribution. This is a substantial simplification because it means we don't have to explicitly specify the domain every time we give a pmf.  In this example, then, the domain is $\mathbb R$ (by default) and the range is $\{1/10, 9/10\}.$  Its *support* is $\{0,1\}.$

Comment: @whuber shouldn't the domain of pmf be finite or countably infinite, by definition?

Comment: That seems to confuse the *domain* with the *support.*  Although there's nothing technically wrong with insisting that the domain of a pmf be just the support of its distribution, it complicates things.  Indeed, one may define a pmf to be *any* function $p:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ for which (a) $p(x)\ge 0$ for all $x$ and (b) $\sum_{x\in\mathbb{R}}p(x)=1.$  As is conventional in algebra, this sum is defined provided at most a countable number of the values of $p$ are nonzero, so that is implicitly included in the latter assertion.

Comment: As an example of how this approach is simpler, consider defining the CDF of the distribution determined by a pmf $p.$  In my definition it is $F(x) = \sum_{y\le x}p(y).$ In  your definition you would have to specify something like $F(x)=\sum_{y\mid y\in\operatorname{Domain}(p)\text{ and } y\le x} p(y).$ Both are correct; both work; take your pick.